# Can I see my Contracts when I am in the field?

Tags: tales-of-xillia-2

I cannot find a list of active (or inactive) jobs when I am in the field. I can only see the list when I am at the job board. Is there any way to see what I need or is the only time it is available at the job board itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can!  It's a bit convoluted, and it won't be limited to just the contracts you've taken, but you can see what current ones you have taken.

Go to Library, then Event List.  Your open quests (including your jobs) are under Underway.  They're also under Jobs, but that includes ones you've completed, so finding your current ones may be somewhat harder to do.

Note that you won't see any elite monster quests here; you don't take those, they just are completed when you kill the monster.